# Using xclip to copy to host clipboard from VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

Here's my current setup:

- Host: MacOS
- VM: Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)
- Hypervisor: Parallels 14
- Host terminal emulator: iTerm2
- Shell: Bash

I do all of my development in my Linux VM (I ssh into the VM, being terminal-only works great for me in my dev environment), and I'm a heavy user of tmux. With that being said, tmux isn't great for doing the typical mouse-drag copy/paste of text.

In the past, I've used xclip (`xclip -sel c`) to dump things on the clipboard. In this case, though, I'd like to dump text from my Linux VM onto the MacOS clipboard. Doing `$ echo hello world | xclip -sel c` gives me an error of:

> Error: Can't open display: (null)

And then if I try to do something like `$ echo hello world | DISPLAY=:0 xclip -sel c` I get another error:

> No protocol specified
>
> Error: Can't open display: :0

Any thoughts on how to get this working? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way X programs work is that they look for a variable called `DISPLAY`, which contains the identity of the X server it should connect to, and then connect to this X server.

There is no X server running on your VM. However, MacOS can run an X server (calls XQuartz), and you can make `ssh` forward X connections to this server (either with `ssh -X` or with the configuration file, see the man pages). This will automatically set `DISPLAY` (check by `echo $DISPLAY`), and establish a "fake X server endpoint" on the VM which can be used by `xclip` etc.

You may have to manually start XQuartz on MacOS, I never tried X forwarding from there.